# accessing object in react with map

Tags: reactjs

I have some difficulties accessing the key/values inside an object even tho i have said it is an array. (.map gave me error)

With axios post i have this type in response

```
 type response = {
    data: [];
  };
```

Response from API:

```
"data": {
        "thisoneineed": false,
        "response": [{
            "ID": "1234",
        }],
        "message": "this is a test message",
    }
```

inside my components i get this from a redux state (i am saving it in the state after the response)

when i try this:

```
Object.entries(state).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key);
})
```

It gives me all they keys inside the array.

What i need to do is to access the value based on a key value so i did like this: (inside a component)

```
 const insurance = useSelector(
    (state: AppState) => state.session.data
);

    Object.entries(insurance).map(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(key[thisoneineed]);
    })
```

This gives:

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'thisoneineed'.

I was woundering how can i access the success key and get the value.

Comment: Why can't you do this directly

`insurance.thisisoneineed`

Comment: TS2339: Property 'thisisoneineed' does not exist on type '[]'.

Comment: But `insurance` is an array or a JSON?

Comment: console.log(typeof(insurance));  this gives me "object"

Comment: console.log(insurance); gives you an array or a JSON?

Comment: typeof([]) or typeof[{}] gives you object itself

Comment: ƒ Object() { [native code] }

Comment: so it's an `Object`, not an `Array`.

Comment: Now it worked. Thanks. the change to "any" did the trick

Comment: @AliDurrani using `any` is not a best practice, would suggest you to figureout the exact type and use it

Answer (score 1):

You have the type defined as

```
type response = {
    data: [];
  };
```

which means it's an empty array, either as hack try changing it to `any` until you figureout the exact type of the response and then give it a correct type

EDIT::

You can try this

```
 const insurance = useSelector(
    (state: AppState) => state.session.data
) as any;

console.log(insurance.thisoneineed)
```

PS: I wont suggest keeping any overthere but until you figure out the exact type of the response you can keep it